# extern const std::string not initialized under iOS, works fine on Windows

Tags: c++, ios, constants

I have a Configurations.h and Configurations.cpp that define some constant string values that are used everywhere in my cross-platform application.
In another file I use some of these values to create other constant strings.
That could look like this:

```
const std::string SHADER_SOURCE_HEAD_ES = Configurations::DEFAULT_SHADER_VERSION_ES + SHADER_SOURCE_LINE_BREAK + "precision mediump float" + SHADER_SOURCE_LINE_ENDING;
```

This works fine on Windows and it worked on iOS as well before I changed everything to be "extern const" in Configurations.h and did the declaration in the cpp-File.

Now on iOS Configurations::DEFAULT_SHADER_VERSION_ES is empty. Configuration.h is of course included first, so the constants should exist (and do on Windows). I also have some functions that use the constants (in the same file as const std::string SHADER_SOURCE_HEAD_ES) and there they work.

What could be wrong here? Thank you so much guys :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like it's an order of initialization issue. A cleaner approach would be to use functions to provide access to those strings. In those functions, make the variable `static` and initialize them appropriately.

For example, instead of using:

```
extern const int myVar;
```

in the .h file and

```
const int myVar = 20;
```

in the .cpp file, use:

```
extern int getMyVar();
```

in the .h file and

```
int getMyVar()
{
   static const int myVar= 20;
   return myVar;
}
```

in the .cpp file.

Comment: Thank you very much, that would certainly work. My only concern is, that I wanted this Configurations.h to be easily readable so everyone can see all my global strings at a quick glance. Wrapping everything up in functions wasn't really my intention ... Is there any other way? I just wanna make sure it's the only/best option before I change about 50 constants to functions and change the rest of my code at various places ;-)

Comment: @Ben, When the global variables don't depend on one another, leaving them as `extern` variables is OK. If they depend on on another, using functions is the right choice. I can't think of a better alternative off-hand.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much. Seems like I have to change a lot of code today ^^